# Is learning game programming with C# and XNA a good idea?

Tags: c#, xna

I would like to start learning some game programming, and I don't know if starting with C# and the XNA engine is a good idea. I know that in the industry, C++ is still the main language for progrmaming games. What do you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Better learn game programming with C# and Unity.

I remember my XNA days were tackled by unrelated problems. In Unity those are hidden under the cover and you can "do your thing" right off the bat.

Soon (2 years from now), you'll realize the limits of Unity and switch to more serious platforms, but by then you'll have learned a huge amount of stuff.

Along with Unity I'd recommend MonoDevelop (embedded in Unity) instead of Visual Studio, Blender, Audacity and (for much much later in your growth, when you'll realize that your games are not fun at all) some books:

"On the Way to Fun" by Roberto Dillon

"Designing Games" by Tynan Sylvester

I tell you all this because it will be IRRELEVANT to your success. Your success will solely depend on your focus to study, study and study. And sacrifice every minute of your time.

Comment: Thanks, you have a point. Learning to use Unity instead of XNA should be a better idea, at least with Unity you can create some more advanced games, I have seen some nice indie games created in it.

Comment: You'll see that Unity is yes, powerful, but still limited. You'll have to program more advanced things in C# and there you'll learn things that can be "hauled" over to other contexts. Knowing how to use Unity's UI and menus is not "game design". Feel free to accept an answer, when the time comes :)